# Using scanner class with a GUI

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using java swing to create my GUI and using the scanner class to get the information inputted from the JTextFields across to the server. is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You don't need to use Scanner when using Swing. And you will realize that once you start working on it.

Comment: Impossible. Look into libraries such as https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo and such and learn a little bit about server client communications.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no console, so don't use Scanner. Instead get text when you need it by using TextField's getText() method.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how Swing works. `Scanner` is only for command-line input. If you have a `JTextField`, just call the `.getText()` method on it.

```
JTextField myField = new JTextField();
...
String currentText = myField.getText();
```

`Swing` is event-based. You probably want to have a `JButton` and have that `JButton` cause the text to be submitted to the server when it is clicked. For that, you'll need an `ActionListener`. See the tutorial below for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Comment: would i then be able to output that to the server using printwriter.

Comment: and then on the server side still use nextline(), to get the text from the user.

Comment: It isn't very clear what your application should be doing. From the client side, you'll need a method that the server can call to get the text from this box (using .getText()) and return it to the server. Then on the server side, you can just System.out.println(theText).